# struct in class is not a type

Tags: c++, class, struct

I need some help with designing and returning a structure. I have done a similar type of structure and am getting an error saying:

> "The a in class c is not a type"

How can I fix this?

a.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct a {
   int i;
   vector<abc> j;
};
```

b.h

```
#include <a.h>
class c{
private: 
    a a_;
    virtual bool execute();
    void compute(&a a1)
public:
    a function_name();
}
```

b.cc

```
#include<b.h>
c::execute()
{
  a aa_ = function_name();
}
```

d.cc

```
#include<b.h>
c::a c::function_name()
{
   compute(a_);
   return *a_;
}
```

Comment: `c::a c::function_name()` => `a c::function_name()`. `a` didn't inherit `c` namespace magically

Comment: Please don't spam irrelevant tags. This is not **C**.

Comment: The fact that you have 4 different files here are not relevant to the question. You are also not showing the actual error message you are getting when compiling. Please take the time to read about what a [mcve] is and how to make one.

Comment: `return *a_; ` ---> 'return a_;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b.h` includes `a.h`, `a` is a type at the global scope, a`a` didn't inherit `c` namespace magically

You'd need `c::a` if you had `a` declared *inside* `c` declaration:

```
class c{
private: 
  struct a {
```

So fix is to remove namespace from `c::a`:

```
a c::function_name()
```

note: the naming conventions used here (if there are some) don't help to understand those examples.

also: `void compute(&a a1)` doesn't compile, should be `void compute(a &a1)`, and `return *a_;` should return a reference so `return a_;`

Comment: The function 'compute(a_)'  throws an error saying not declared in scope.

Comment: `void compute(&a a1)` doesn't compile: `void compute(a &a1)`

Comment: Thank you very much